# the integral of the inverse of a Fourier series

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\{a_h\}$ be a double-sided complex sequence such that $\sum_{h=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_i| <\infty$ with $a_{0}\neq0$.

Set $f(x) :=  \sum_{h=-\infty}^{\infty}  a_h \exp(ixh)$ and
 assume that $f(x) >c >0$.

I wish to compute the integral
\begin{eqnarray}
\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{ f(x)} dx.
\end{eqnarray}
My conjecture (or hope) is that 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{f(x)} dx = \frac{2\pi}{a_0}.
\end{eqnarray}
Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the case. For instance, for $f(x)=1+\frac12\sin x$, that [integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201/%281%2b%28sin%20x%29/2%29%20for%20x=-pi,pi) is $4\pi/\sqrt3\ne2\pi$.

Comment: There is something that I would like to understand. At wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Inverting_series , you see that inversion of the Fourier series would give $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{a_0}-\frac{a_1}{a_0^2}e^{ix}+\ldots$. How does this cope with your counterexample and the OP hypothesis?

Comment: @Jon: That result is for power series with positive exponents; the Fourier series has positive and negative exponents. If you replace $\sin x$ by $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$ in my example, the [integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%281%2B%28exp+%28i+x%29%29%2F2%29+for+x%3D-pi%2Cpi) is $2\pi$, as predicted by the power series result. You can think of it as writing the denominator as $a_0+x$ and expanding around $x=0$; then if $x$ contains only positive powers, no other constant terms appear, but if it contains positive and negative powers, they do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you  for your help.  From the arguments above, can  I understand that $\int_{\pi}^{\pi} 1/f(x) dx = 2\pi/a_0$ holds if the series only has nonnegative exponents?

Comment: @Haruo: Note that the Wikipedia article Jon quoted is about *formal* power series, so you might also have to think about convergence. At least formally, though, if the series has only non-negative exponents, the constant term of its reciprocal is the reciprocal of the (non-zero) constant term. Note that for Fourier series, a series with only non-negative exponents is necessarily complex.

Comment: Thanks for detailed comments. My conjecture dose not always hold even for a Fourier series with only non-negative exponents. For specific $f$ with non-negative exponents,  I have to be care about the convergence of the expansion of $1/f(x)$.